Kubernetes (CRI-O) cannot ping to any host
Cannot ping to any host from kubenetes pod.
Needed functionality: Ping between 2 kubernetes pods
Expected result: Successful ping between 2 pods.
Current output:
pod/kube-server-rtt-3 created
pod/kube-client-rtt-3 created
pod/kube-server-rtt-3 condition met
pod/kube-client-rtt-3 condition met
command terminated with exit code 1
Kubernetes RTT benchmark-3 done
@kube:~/Documents$ cat kubeIperf3_RTT_3.txt
PING 10.85.0.123 (10.85.0.123) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 10.85.0.123 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 4103ms
Used docker image:
https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/arnedh/dockerbench/general
The script :

kubectl run kube-server-rtt-$i --image=$image --restart=Never --overrides='{"spec": {"tolerations": [{"key": "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane", "operator": "Exists", "effect": "NoSchedule"}], "containers": [{"name": "kube-server-rtt-'$i'", "image": "'$image'", "command": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep infinity"], "securityContext": {"capabilities": {"add": ["NET_RAW"]}}}]}}'
kubectl run kube-client-rtt-$i --image=$image --restart=Never --overrides='{"spec": {"tolerations": [{"key": "node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane", "operator": "Exists", "effect": "NoSchedule"}], "containers": [{"name": "kube-client-rtt-'$i'", "image": "'$image'", "command": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep infinity"], "securityContext": {"capabilities": {"add": ["NET_RAW"]}}}]}}'
Wait for the pods to be ready
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod/kube-server-rtt-$i --timeout=600s
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pod/kube-client-rtt-$i --timeout=600s
Get the needed IP address of the server
serverIP=8.8.8.8 #$(kubectl get pod kube-server-rtt-$i -o=jsonpath='{.status.podIP}')
Perform RTT test
kubectl exec kube-client-rtt-$i -- ping -c 5 $serverIP > kubeIperf3_RTT_$i.txt
echo "Kubernetes RTT benchmark-$i done"
Remove the pods
kubectl delete pod kube-server-rtt-$i
kubectl delete pod kube-client-rtt-$i

Thanks in advance!
(default namespace, no limits on ping functionality)
